# Is a link without the protocol valid XHTML? i.e. <a href="//www.example.com/">

Tags: http, xhtml, https, anchor, href

Is it valid XHTML / good practice to have links of the following form?
//www.example.com/foo/bar.html

If the current page is HTTP, then the link points to: http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html
If the current page is secured under HTTPS, then the link points to: https://www.example.com/foo/bar.html

In other words, is

> <a href="//www.example.com/">

valid in XHTML 1.1 <del>Strict</del>?  And, is it supported by many/all browsers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it valid XHTML

Completely. XHTML doesn't care about the syntax of URIs. The href attribute is defined as containing CDATA.

> valid in XHTML 1.1 Strict?

There is no such language.

XHTML 1.0 has Strict / Transitional / Frameset versions.

XHTML 1.1 is just XHTML 1.1. (And isn't blessed by [rfc2854](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2854.txt) for serving as text/html (which you need for IE < 9 support)).

> And, is it supported by many/all browsers?

Yes. Support is fine.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for your response. Just trying to not upset the W3C police. :P  All my pages must be valid XHTML, ya know.