# method to for http or https based on current url?

Tags: html, http, https

I'd like to redirect users to http urls if they came to my website with `http://`
and i'd like to redirect them to https urls if they came to my website with `https://`

is there a way to provide urls for example:

```
 ://foo.com/bar
```

or any other method to create a link on the page based on the same http method that the user got in ?

i prefer a solution that is based on pure html without javascript

## update

thanks for the quick responses.

unfortunately i forgot to mention that I redirect to a different subdomain
so i cannot omit the domain name

thanks!

Kfir

Comment: try `/bar` as the `href`

Comment: Like simply omitting the host name?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario correct. I'm trying to find it documented.

Comment: oh sorry.. i redirect to a different domain

Comment: Then you have to include the protocol as well.

Comment: so i need to include each url dynamically based on javascript code to test if the current url is http or https?

Comment: That would be a solution. Alternatively, you could do it on the server.

Comment: I recommend the server-side approach.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735777/is-a-link-without-the-protocol-valid-xhtml-i-e-a-href-www-example-com

Comment: what about '///domain/url' ? still testing but so far so good

Comment: @extramaster should this question be closed with your link as a duplicate?

Comment: yeah i voted to close it :)